# How to merge more than 1 cell value with a comma in a single cell of a row with some restrictions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-schema

I Have Table 1. I want Output as Table 2
Please help me

```
Table 1
Student_ID AttCode AttDate
101        AE      1-1-2011
101        H       1-2-2011
101        T       1-5-2011
101        H       1-7-2011
101        AU      1-8-2011
102        AE      1-1-2011
102        AE      1-3-2011
102        H       1-4-2011
102        V       1-5-2011

Table 2
Student_ID FromDate  To date   ConsecutiveAbs AttCodes
101        1-1-2011  1-2-2011  2              AE,H
101        1-5-2011  1-8-2011  4              T,AE,H,AU
102        1-1-2011  1-1-2011  1              AE
102        1-3-2011  1-5-2011  2              AE,H,V
```

Comment: what's the grouping logic?

Comment: how can decide from which attdate to attdate. have any logic.
please describe your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! Complete script, just make sure to test really well for every possible case and don't forget to mark it as an answer if it fits your needs:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEST1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TEST1
GO
CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
STUDENTID INT ,
ATTCODE VARCHAR(2) ,
ATTDATE DATE
)
GO
INSERT INTO TEST1
VALUES 
('101','AE','20110101'),
('101','H','20110102'),
('101','T','20110105'),
('101','H','20110107'),
('101','AU','20110108'),
('102','AE','20110101'),
('102','AE','20110103'),
('102','H','20110104'),
('102','V','20110105')
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('TEST2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TEST2
GO

CREATE TABLE TEST2
(
STUDENTID INT,
FROMDATE DATE,
TODATE DATE,
CONSECUTIVEABS INT,
ATTCODES VARCHAR(255)
)
GO

INSERT INTO TEST2
SELECT TEST1.STUDENTID,TEST1.ATTDATE,TEST1.ATTDATE,1,TEST1.ATTCODE
FROM TEST1
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT STUDENTID,MIN(ATTDATE) ATTDATE
    FROM TEST1
    GROUP BY STUDENTID
    ) MI ON MI.STUDENTID=TEST1.STUDENTID AND MI.ATTDATE=TEST1.ATTDATE

DECLARE @STUDENTID INT, @ATTCODE VARCHAR(2), @ATTDATE DATE

DECLARE CRS CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT TEST1.STUDENTID,TEST1.ATTCODE,TEST1.ATTDATE
FROM TEST1
LEFT JOIN TEST2 ON TEST1.STUDENTID=TEST2.STUDENTID AND TEST1.ATTCODE=TEST2.ATTCODES AND TEST1.ATTDATE=TEST2.FROMDATE
WHERE TEST2.STUDENTID IS NULL
ORDER BY 1,3 ASC

OPEN CRS

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @STUDENTID, @ATTCODE, @ATTDATE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TEST2
    WHERE STUDENTID=@STUDENTID AND DATEADD(DD,1,TODATE)=@ATTDATE
    )
        UPDATE TEST2
        SET TODATE=@ATTDATE, ATTCODES+=','+@ATTCODE, CONSECUTIVEABS+=1
        WHERE STUDENTID=@STUDENTID AND DATEADD(DD,1,TODATE)=@ATTDATE
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO TEST2
        SELECT @STUDENTID,@ATTDATE,@ATTDATE,1,@ATTCODE


    FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @STUDENTID, @ATTCODE, @ATTDATE
END


SELECT * FROM TEST2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

One case it doesn't deal with is when you have the same studenId and attdate and different attcode in the input table. You haven't mentioned anything about this case that's why it is not dealt by the code above.